# Django file upload for different apps within a project?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am working on a project which have various apps like protocol, prediction etc.

to perform some calculation "protocol" and "prediction" apps requires user input in the form of file upload.

I have implemented the bellow schema which uploads file successfully into the "media" directory which is present at the base project directory.

I want to implement file upload in this way so that  It can upload file for respective app directory rather a common media directory.

My code was like this:

Views.py

```
def simple_upload(request):

    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['myfile']:
        myfile = request.FILES['myfile']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
        uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)
        print uploaded_file_url

        return render(request, 'protocol/submit_job.html', {})

    return render(request, 'protocol/main_protocol.html')
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^protocol/$', views.simple_upload, name='simple_upload'),
```

html

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div class="heading">
 <h1> Machine Learning Modeling.. </h1>
 <h2> Upload CSV files .. </h2>
 </div>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input class="input" type="file" name="myfile">
    <button class="button" type="submit"> Upload file  and submit job </button>
  </form>

  {% if uploaded_file_url %}
    <p class="text" >File uploaded successfully. </p>
  {% endif %}
```

this schema work for me and upload all the file into media directory..
What changes should I make to upload file in app specific manner.

for example:

```
prediction/Input/uploaded_file_1.csv
protocol/Input/uploaded_file_2.csv
```

I don't want to save or upload  any file into model or database. Appl will delete uploaded file just before the next user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FileSystemStorage class has the `location` parameter, and the default is set to `MEDIA_ROOT`, but you can change it to any other directory.

First, change the default location for the class:

```
fs = FileSystemStorage(location='prediction/Input/')
```

And then you save the file in the same way you are doing right now. Don't forget the write permissions.

Here is the documentation for the class:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/files/storage/#the-filesystemstorage-class

Comment: This is the most relevant  Answer for my problem, I just changed  only one line and magic happened :). Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

If you have a FileField that you use for referencing the file in you model then you can use the `upload_to` attribute to do this. It could be something like the following code:

```
from os import path

def _upload_path(instance, filename):
    return path.join(instance._meta.app_label, 'Input', filename)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=_upload_path)
```

I haven't tested the above code. If you are able to use the code, please get back with a feedback.

If you are not using the model to select upload directory then use code in your views to do so. The following code is for uploading a single file:

```
def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    with open('some/file/name.txt', 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
```

You can edit the upload path according to your needs. For example I have used the above code in my view to upload multiple files without using models in my project.

```
def Upload(request):
    for count, x in enumerate(request.FILES.getlist("files")):
        def process(f):
            with open('/Users/Michel/django_1.8/projects/upload/media/file_' + str(count), 'wb+') as destination:
                for chunk in f.chunks():
                    destination.write(chunk)
        process(x)
    return HttpResponse("File(s) uploaded!")
```

Comment: I don't want to upload any file into model or database.

Comment: Then you need to do it from the view. Can you direct the users to two separate views for the apps? I have updated the answer. Please take a look @jax